# LPs having a 'stable' objective value wrt changes in the constraint right-hand sides

Tags: linear-programming, sensitivity-analysis, continuous-optimization

I have a problem as:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+}{\min} & c^\top x \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & Ax \leq \mathbf{1} \cdot b ,
\end{array}
\end{align}
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is an arbitrary data matrix and all the constraints have $b > 0 $ on the right-hand side.

I am looking for the terminology (and in a broader sense, the relevant literature) studying "if we increase $b$ arbitrarily small, we can also bound the change in the optimal objective value with an arbitrarily small change." Or more formally maybe:

> Take $b_1 > 0$, and denote $OPT_1$ as the optimal objective value when the above problem has $b_1$ on the right-hand side of the constraint. For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $b_2 < b_1$, such that $OPT_2 - OPT_1 < \epsilon$, where $b_2$ is a function of $\epsilon$ and $OPT_2$ denotes the optimal objective value of the above LP when the right-hand side is $b_2$.

My main goal is to analyze this for a continuous LP where the variable becomes a Borel measure, the objective becomes $\int_{\mathbb z \in R} c(z) \mathrm{d}x(z) $ and the $i$-th constraint becomes $\int_{\mathbb R} a_i(z)\mathrm{d}x(z) \leq b$ where $a_i$ are also Borel functions. I am hoping the answer for the simpler LP example above will let me generalize to this case.

Comment: Sensitivity analysis

Comment: The bound you want comes from LP duality theory.

Comment: @user3680510 I don’t think this is sensitivity analysis. Sensitivity analysis tells us the change in the objective with a unit change in each right hand side. What if we cannot “bound” this by changing the right hand side of every constraint at once?

Answer (score 2):

The property that some infinitesimal change in one of the constraints impacts the objective is called "a constraint being active" or "a constraint being in conflict with the objective".

> "if we increase $b$ arbitrarily small, we can also bound the change in the optimal objective value with an arbitrarily small change."

This property is called "the objective being lipschitz continuous with regard to $b$". In my intuition this should hold all LPs that have a non empty simplex. If you push $b$ so that the simplex becomes empty you can't reason about the meaning of the objective.

> > Take $b_1 > 0$, and denote $OPT_1$ as the optimal objective value when the above problem has $b_1$ on the right-hand side of the constraint. For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $b_2 < b_1$, such that $OPT_2 - OPT_1 < \epsilon$, where $b_2$ is a function of $\epsilon$ and $OPT_2$ denotes the optimal objective value of the above LP when the right-hand side is $b_2$.

This property is called "the objective being continuous with regard to $b$" and is implied by the former under the same concerns of the simplex being non empty.